# How do I create a simple custom footline with Frankfurt (in Beamer)?

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I very much would appreciate someone's help with this. I would like to create a very simple footline in my Beamer presentation, and none of what I've found is suiting me (and I'm having trouble customizing -- I'm relatively new to Beamer).

What I want is for my name to be on the left, and to have the frame slide number (out of total, e.g. 30/31) on the right, and I want the background color to be the same as the background for the very top headline (or the color for the frame title would be fine).

An image of roughly what I am hoping to achieve is attached (though with with the frame # instead of University on the right). I like the white line underneath as well, so it'd be great if that could be preserved (though not necessary).  The result in the screenshot was achieved by combining multiple themes (which I am trying to avoid, and I was helped earlier to avoid this), which is why the MWE does not exactly correspond to the screenshot.

Thank you in advance for any help!

[image]

```
%\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
%\documentclass[10pt, handout]{beamer} %for no pauses

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{adjustbox}

 \usetheme{Frankfurt}
 \usecolortheme{dolphin} \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{111,110,200} \setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=myblue} \setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=myblue}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\inserttocsectionnumber.~\inserttocsection}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
    \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
\end{frame}
}

\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=MediumBlue}

\title{Title}

\author{Name}

\institute[University] 
{
  Department \\
  University \\
  }
% - Use the \inst command only if there are several affiliations.
% - Keep it simple, no one is interested in your street address.

\date{DATE}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Sample} 
\begin{frame}{Sample}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Test 
    \item Test 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: this seems to do roughly what I wanted (though it'd be great to know if there's a way to make the footline color lighter than the headline color!)

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,left]{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\hspace*{1em}\insertshortauthor~~\beamer@ifempty{\insertshortinstitute}{}{(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Depending on how light the color should be, you could try `author in head/foot` or `date in head/foot` instead of `section in head/foot`.

Comment: Do you miss a `\makeatletter` at the beginning?